# make jQuery slider navigation only affect closest class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a little problem with a jQuery slider I have developed.

My structure is like this:

div with class of `category-wrapper`

--div with class of `product-nav`

----div with class of `rightarrow-nav`, and div with class `leftarrow-nav`. these both should control `.product-wrapper`

--div with class of `product-wrapper`

As you can see from the fiddle example, the left and right arrows currently control both `product-wrappers`. I need to know how I can change the code to only affect the product-wrapper that is within the category-wrapper of the right or left arrow that is clicked.
[Fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonyb/ygEU6/)
I think it has something to do with this line:

```
$('.rightarrow-nav').parent(".product-nav").next(".product-wrapper").scrollTo(element, 800, {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is referring to all the arrows at the same time, you need to specify somewhere which arrow is actually being clicked, and limit your scrollToPosition function to just that element.  Right now it refers to all of the buttons, so obviously they scroll all of the divs regardless of which one was clicked.

First, when you call the scrollToPosition, you need to tell it which button was actually clicked.  You can do that by passing `$(this)` as another argument.

```
scrollToPosition(posts[position += 1], $(this));
```

Then, in the function, accept that argument and apply your code just to that element (`myel`).

```
function scrollToPosition(element, myel) {
event.preventDefault()
    if (element !== undefined) {
           $(myel).parent(".product-nav").next(".product-wrapper").scrollTo(element, 800, {
          //  $(".product-nav").parent(".category-wrapper").find('.product-wrapper').scrollTo(element, 800, {
            margin: true
        });
    }
}
```

See the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ygEU6/3/

Comment: Thanks for the really quick reply. but I think there is a bug. on the top set, click to the next, then scroll down and click on the next in the next section, now go back to the first next button again. It seems to skip 2 frames. Any ideas?. This was with your JSFiddle

Comment: Basically you are having the same problem with your posts variable.  You are using the same one for all of the scrolling elements. You need to define the position of each element separately.

Comment: Ok, I have had a look and tried some things with the Posts variable but I cant get it right. Can you fix it in your fiddle and Ill look to see what you have done? thanks for the help it is much appreciated :)